# Recreating SUMIFS in SQL with conditional logic

Tags: sql, excel, sumifs

I'm having a difficult time writing the SQL I'm able to accomplish with Excel SUMIFS.  The ultimate goal is create share of requirement (loyalty) metric for each Customer.  In the below, I'm trying to create the Category_Sales column.  All other columns I already have in my SQL.
Here is what my Excel SUMIFS looks like.

```
=(Brand_Sales (range) , Cust_ID (range), Cust_ID (row), First_Buy (range), >=Brand_Str (row), Last Buy (range) <=, Brand_End (row))
```

The 268 value for Innocent is attained from the sum of Innocent, Cresco, Supply, and PTS since their First_Buy & Last_Buys are all inside the range of the Innocent Brand Start & End.

| State | Brand | Cust_ID | First_Buy | Last_Buy | Brand_Str | Brand_End | Brand_Sales | Category_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IL | Innocent | xyz | 4/9/2022 | 4/9/2022 | 4/7/2022 | 5/29/2022 | 64 | 268 |
| IL | Cresco | xyz | 4/15/2022 | 4/15/2022 | 1/1/2022 | 5/30/2022 | 57 | 446 |
| IL | Supply | xyz | 4/15/2022 | 4/15/2022 | 1/1/2022 | 5/30/2022 | 45 | 446 |
| IL | Rythm | xyz | 1/3/2022 | 1/13/2022 | 1/1/2022 | 5/30/2022 | 121 | 446 |
| IL | Natures | xyz | 1/22/2022 | 1/22/2022 | 1/1/2022 | 5/30/2022 | 57 | 446 |
| IL | PTS | xyz | 4/26/2022 | 4/26/2022 | 1/1/2022 | 5/30/2022 | 102 | 446 |

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of  `SUM(CASE WHEN [condition] THEN brand_sales END)`. It looks like you have multiple conditions which can be strung together like so: (`[condition] AND [condition]`)

Comment: First, please show us what the data looks like in your database (table definitions, etc), then read `SQL` tag description, then tag the DBMS you are using : *Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL.*